# Xcode tap gesture causing error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I created two views in Xcode using the hierarchical view layout. I initially created a button on the first page (PlaylistMasterViewController) which activates the segue method to transition to the next page in the hierarchy (PlaylistDetailViewController), which worked just fine. I then deleted the button, and added a tap gesture to one of the UIImage view elements in the masterViewController and deleted the button. I created the action outlet of the touch gesture to activate the segue and made sure to delete all of the uses of the button in my code, yet this error is thrown once right after the splash screen loads (run time). Any ideas what might be causing this?

[image: Xcode error console output]

Comment: when a view gets removed, are you also removing the gesture with it?  This is not automatic

Comment: it happens when an outlet is connected in the interface builder but you deleted the outlet property from the code , probably a property outlet. Check all the outlets are properly connected or if some or missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your storyboard check your `PlaylistMasterViewController` for a connected outlet named `showPlaylistDetail` with a little while exclamation mark next to it.  Then hit the 'x' and clear that outlet connection.

It's most likely some outlet you previously connected and later removed from your code.

The image below is just an example to show you what it would look like.

[image]

Comment: great that cleared up the error and will allow the app to run!

Answer (score 0):

most common - you have outlet from ViewController to your deleted button in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You might have deleted the button but something in the view itself may still be referencing it. As the view is loaded at runtime when you try to bring up the view it may have UIButton connected to an outlet that no longer exists.

Open the view in Interface Builder and make all the ui elements in that view are properly wired up and not referencing a non-existent IBOutlet. If there is a problem you'll see a yellow warning icon to indicate a problem.